# sanely run all scripts in a directory

Tags: bash, debian

I would like to create a shell-script that in turn runs all scripts it finds in a given directory.

The following restrictions should apply:

- the scripts ought to be run in alphabetical order
- backup-scripts (aka scripts that look like typical backup scripts, like `foo~` or `bar.bak`) shall be omitted.
- arguments should be passed to the scripts
- only "scripts" (executable files and probably symlinks pointing to executable files) should be run

I find this a common pattern in split-configurations (on my Debian system), and I quite like it.

Now I've created an simple startup script that seems to do all this:

```
#!/bin/sh

SCRIPTDIR=/etc/scripts/up.d

for SCRIPT in "${SCRIPTDIR}/"*
do
  case "${SCRIPT}" in
  *~|*.bak)
     continue
  ;;
  *)
     if [ -f "${SCRIPT}" -a -x "${SCRIPT}" ]; then
       "${SCRIPT}" $@
     fi
  ;;
  esac
done
```

Since the pattern is so common, I wonder whether there is already such a script installed on my system, which supposedly has seen more testing and bug-fixing than mine. however I cannot find one.

Do you know of such a starter-script on Debian systems?

Comment: [`run-parts`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/run-parts.8)?

Comment: yes i think that was it. i just couldn't find it!

Comment: You might want to rename all the scripts to *.sh *.bash or something. Then you can use *.sh to get your files and you will be sure nothing else in the directory will be executed. Dumb, but it works.

Comment: @muru so does `run-parts` allow me to pass an arbitrary list of arguments?

Comment: No, you can only pass a common argument to all the scripts (not separate arguments to separate scripts).

Comment: You can build the command line: `for i; do args+=(" -a '$i'"); done`, then use `run-parts ... ${args[@]} ...`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`run-parts`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/run-parts.8) command:

```
run-parts  runs  all  the  executable  files  named  within constraints
described  below,  found  in  directory  directory.   Other  files  and
directories are silently ignored.

If neither the --lsbsysinit option nor the --regex option is given then
the names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case letters,
ASCII digits, ASCII underscores, and ASCII minus-hyphens.
```

The default restrictions ignore files with extensions, tildes, etc. You can pass multiple arguments by passing multiple `--arg` options to `run-parts`:

```
-a, --arg=argument
        pass  argument to the scripts.  Use --arg once for each argument
        you want passed.
```

You can build the argument list to be passed:

```
for i; do args+=(" -a '$i'"); done
run-parts ... "${args[@]}" ...
```

It is used, for example, by the default `crontab` to execute the scripts in the various `cron.*` directories.

Comment: This is great, needed to run all files named test-* in a folder named "bin": `run-parts bin/ --regex test-*` did the job! Add `--exit-on-error` to make the execution stop when a execution fails.